How to deal with an HDD that is totally missing after a power cut in Windows 11?
My HDD disappeared after a power cut, like I cannot access my D: or E: drive.
Now if I try to open something, it says:

The drive or network connection that shortcut 'shortcut-name.lnk' refers to is unavailable. Make sure that the disk is properly inserted or the network resource is available, and then try again.

I tried re-scanning on Disk Management and I couldn't find it, and I even tried looking for it in Device Manager and still no luck.
Then I tried reconnecting the HDD but there were no results.
Is there a way to fix this?

What interface does the HDD have? Can you try connecting to a different port and/or try a different cable to try and determine if the fault is on the HDD rather than say the port it is connected to in the PC?

One idea is trying to connect it to a Powered SATA to USB adapter, if it shows up try a tool like crystal disk info and check its status and copy all the data to another drive.

If the HDD doesn't show up in either disk management, device management or BIOS/UEFI then it's very likely a goner. Replace and restore from backup.
There's a very slight chance that connectivity to the drive has become faulty. Power down, unplug and replug both power and SATA connectors on the drive and (SATA only) on the mainboard. Power up and if you're very lucky the drive shows up again.
Additional diagnostics include listening for the HDD to spin up on power. It should spin up (a buzz quickly rising in frequency) and then make a few 'scratching' noises when initializing. Failure to spin up (completely), continuous scratching or no noise at all indicate a dead drive.
